# How to swap array elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays, swap

I have an array

```
           Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (                                
                            [order_id] => 1318
                            [code] => shipping
                            [title] => UK Shipping  (Weight: 0.00kg)
                            [value] => 10.2000                                
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (

                            [order_id] => 1318
                            [code] => sub_total
                            [title] => Sub-Total
                            [value] => 4.7000                                
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (                                
                            [order_id] => 1318
                            [code] => coupon
                            [title] => Coupon (10P)
                            [value] => -0.4700                                
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (                                
                            [order_id] => 1318
                            [code] => tax
                            [title] => VAT (20%)
                            [value] => 2.8860
                            [sort_order] => 8
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (                                
                            [order_id] => 1318
                            [code] => total
                            [title] => Total
                            [value] => 17.3160                                
                        )
                    )
```

I want to swap the array index.
I want to swap the array index when [code] => coupon to [code] => sub_total, If coupon is available.
I want the position of coupon to above the subtotal.
I want the position of sub_total to above the vat.
How is it possible?
Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom sort order array that puts each of the possible values of `code` in the order you want.

```
$custom_sort_order = array(
    'shipping' => 1,
    'coupon' => 2,
    'sub_total' => 3,
    'tax' => 4,
    'total' => 5);
```

then you can use that custom sort order in the comparison function of `usort` to get the array items in your desired order.

```
usort($your_array, function($x, $y) use ($custom_sort_order) {

    // find the sort number for each item
    $x = $custom_sort_order[$x['code']];
    $y = $custom_sort_order[$y['code']];

    // do the comparison
    if ($x == $y) return 0;
    return $x - $y;
});
```